# What is the stylistic device used in this poem?

Tags: poetry

I am not sure if there is a kind of stylistic device in below poem sentence.

> The king’s horses are purebloods, his barns cut stone; roans, blacks, dapples, bays; the granite reds, greys, blues.

If I understand correctly, the "normal" sequence should be:

> The king’s horses are purebloods, roans, blacks, dapples, bays; his barns cut stone, the granite reds, greys, blues.

Is there a name/term for this in poetry?

Comment: homework questions are against the rules here. Take it up with principles.

Comment: Ha, it looks like, but it is not. I just want to know what it is called in English ~

Comment: @gerry: You could be a little more gracious in asking for help.

Comment: @Robusto: I apologize.

Comment: @Rhodri: Yeah. I have checked common stylistic devices, but they all seems different things. Some more famous example may help. But I can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be "synchysis". The sources do not entirely agree. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchysis) and [ChangingMindes](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/figures_speech/synchysis.htm) both give a definition (unreferenced, unfortunately) which is exactly what you are asking, but [rhetoric.byu](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/S/synchysis.htm) has a more general definition.

(I've never come across the word before, so thanks for asking!)

Comment: Great! It really is ~ You and your answer, kind and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of *[parataxis](http://www.yourdictionary.com/parataxis)*. Or you may simply be thinking of a grammatical series.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. The question is updated now

Comment: @gerry: Do you mean subordinate clauses filled with lists, all relating back to an initial subject?

Comment: Yes. I think they are parts of previous sentences, are drawn by the author to impress colors. I don't know if it is common enough to have a name or just specific simplified clauses .